# Python list object mutation

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a python data structure which is a list of dict, like:

```
data = [
   {
       'user':{
          'name': 'INIT_NAME'
          'age': 18
       },
       'cart':{
          ...
       }
   },
   ...
]
```

my objective is to parse every single attr in the dict, so that i could  replace the string with upper cap to a specified value. For example, i would like to parse the data structure above to:

```
data = [
   {
       'user':{
          'name': 'my name'
          'age': 18
       },
       'cart':{
          ...
       }
   },
   ...
]
```

of cause, i would do this by python code like:

```
for d in data:
  for type, attrs in d.items():
    for key, value in attrs.items():
      attrs[key] = parse_attr(value)

def parse_attr(value):
  if value == 'INIT_NAME':
    return 'my name'
```

Sure it will work, but sames it is not quite readable and little hard to knowing what is going on by a glance.

I just wonder are there any simplier way better than this? I am care about code readability therefore i am looking for a better approach. I am just new to python and just know the basic like decorator and syntactic sugar which is not helping in this case. Please let me know if you have any idea. Thank you

Comment: thanks for pointing out my mistake, correction made.

Comment: I think your loop is totally fine. Of course, if you only need to affect the `user` and `name` then you can just index them directly, e.g. `d['user']['name'] = parse_value(d['user']['name'])`. But if you might need to replace any one of the dicts then you'll need a nested loop like you've got. Either way, your code is very very clear and any other methods would actually likely do the opposite. Syntactic sugar when doing nested lookups can actually be quite confusing.

Comment: Your function doesn't quite so it. It will dry most things to None.

Comment: Also, this is asking for code review, not solving an actual problem. Check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Though, note that on Code Review [we need to see real, concrete code, and understand the context in which the code is used.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)